# Delete rows in MySQL matching two columns in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and would like to delete entries from table T1:

```
user_id  level_id  other_data
   1        5         ...
   2        7         ...
   :
```

where the `user_id` and `level_id` values appear together in table T2:

```
user_id  level_id
   1         5
   2         6
```

In this example, the first row would be deleted from table T1.

I tried:

```
delete from T1 where (user_id,level_id) in select user_id,level_id from T2;
```

but that has a syntax error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Try using `exists`:

```
delete from T1
    where exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.level_id = t2.level_id
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks, both for the solution and the encouraging words.  I hadn't known that "select 1" pattern.

Comment: @espertus . . . Some databases (such as Postgres) actually accept a syntax very close to what you wrote.  All subqueries should be in parentheses, but otherwise Postgres would accept it.